# Excel Lookup IP addresses in multiple ranges

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, match

I am trying to find a formula for column `A` that will check an IP address in column `B` and find if it falls into a range (or between) 2 addresses in two other columns `C` and `D`.

E.G.

```
     A           B             C             D
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| valid?  | address     | start       | end        |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| yes     | 10.1.1.5    | 10.1.1.0    | 10.1.1.31  |
| Yes     | 10.1.3.13   | 10.1.2.16   | 10.1.2.31  |
| no      | 10.1.2.7    | 10.1.1.128  | 10.1.1.223 |
| no      | 10.1.1.62   | 10.1.3.0    | 10.1.3.127 |
| yes     | 10.1.1.9    | 10.1.4.0    | 10.1.4.255 |
| no      | 10.1.1.50   | …           | …          |
| yes     | 10.1.1.200  |             |            |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

This is supposed to represent an Excel table with 4 columns a heading and 7 rows as an example.
I can do a lateral check with

```
=IF(AND((B3>C3),(B3 < D3)),"yes","no")
```

which only checks 1 address against the range next to it.
I need something that will check the 1 IP address against all of the ranges. i.e. rows 1 to 100.

This is checking access list rules against routes to see if I can eliminate redundant rules... but has other uses if I can get it going.
To make it extra special I can not use VBA macros to get it done.

I'm thinking some kind of index match to look it up in an array but not sure how to apply it. I don't know if it can even be done. Good luck.

Comment: "I can do a lateral check with `=IF(AND((B3>C3),(B3 < D3)),"yes","no")`".  Really?!  You'd have to break down each `address`, `start`, and `end` into octets and evaluate them individually to do what you're asking.  The only solution I can think of would probably require ~12-14 helper columns.

Comment: Yes the initial lateral check seems to fail. for various addresses...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I've been tracking this problem since my initial comment, but have not taken the time to answer because just like Lana B:

> I like a good puzzle, but it's not a good use of time if i have to keep guessing

+1 to Lana for her patience and effort on this question.

However, IP addressing is something I deal with regularly, so I decided to tackle this one for my own benefit.  Also, *no offense*, but getting the `MIN` of the start and the `MAX` of the end is wrong.  This will not account for gaps in the IP white-list. As I mentioned, this required 15 helper columns and my result is simply `1` or `0` corresponding to `In` or `Out` respectively.  Here is a screenshot (with formulas shown below each column):

[image: Valid IP address worksheet screenshot]

The formulas in `F2:J2` are:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(B2,1,FIND(".",B2)-1))              
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(B2,FIND(".",B2)+1,FIND(".",B2,FIND(".",B2)+1)-1-FIND(".",B2)))         
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(B2,FIND(".",B2,FIND(".",B2)+1)+1,FIND(".",B2,FIND(".",B2,FIND(".",B2)+1)+1)-1-FIND(".",B2,FIND(".",B2)+1)))        
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(B2,FIND(".",B2,FIND(".",B2,FIND(".",B2)+1)+1)+1,LEN(B2)))  
=F2*256^3+G2*256^2+H2*256+I2
```

Yes, I used formulas instead of "Text to Columns" to automate the process of adding more information to a "living" worksheet.

The formulas in `L2:P2` are the same, but replace `B2` with `C2`.

The formulas in `R2:V2` are also the same, but replace `B2` with `D2`.

The formula for `X2` is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($P$2:$P$8<=J2)*--($V$2:$V$8>=J2))
```

I also copied your original "valid" set in column `A`, which you'll see matches my result.

Comment: I can see now.  I don't even know what white spaces are, so I simply parsed numbers, you're right. Technically speaking, for the brief provided without enough details and a very limited data sample, my answer is relevant, and I still enjoyed working on this. But your answer is pretty cool and solves the issue.  I'm going to take time to get my head around it properly after work - it's a good learning for me all round. Thanks!

Comment: @LanaB Yes, I learn much more from answering than asking. Also, I appreciate you laying the groundwork for understanding the problem statement.  I wouldn't have tried without the comments on your answer.

Comment: Thank both of you (@LanaB) so much for your input on this.
Sorry i couldn't be clearer on the Question. My routing table (address ranges) is over 20K rows and I am reluctant to publish real routes( even if they are protected), so there is a fair bit of checking and error correction on my part . I had to use a lookup table with the mask to get the end IP addresses correct in the right octet column.
The key was  =F2*256^3+G2*256^2+H2*256+I2 and =SUMPRODUCT(--($P$2:$P$8<=J2)*--($V$2:$V$8>=J2)) to do a comparison.
Again, Really appreciate your help on this,
Regards
Drew

Comment: At the end of the day, IP addresses are binary numbers.  It's easy to forget that.  Glad you got it fixed!  Please mark the correct answer so we can help others.

Answer (score 3):

You will need helper columns.

- Organise your data as outlined in the picture.
- Split address, start and end into columns by comma (ribbon menu Data=>Text To Columns).
- Above the start/end parts, calculate MIN FOR START, and MAX FOR END for all split text parts (i.e. MIN(K5:K1000) .

FORMULAS:

VALIDITY formula - copy into cell D5, and drag down:

```
=IF(AND(B6>$I$1,B6<$O$1),"In",
   IF(OR(B6<$I$1,B6>$O$1),"Out",
     IF(B6=$I$1,
       IF(C6<$J$1, "Out",
         IF( C6>$J$1, "In",
           IF( D6<$K$1,  "Out",
             IF( D6>$K$1, "In",
               IF(E6>=$L$1, "In", "Out"))))),
     IF(B6=$O$1,
       IF(C6>$P$1, "Out",
         IF( C6<$P$1, "In",
           IF( D6>$Q$1,  "Out",
             IF( D6<$Q$1, "In",
               IF(E6<=$R$1, "In", "Out") ))))   )
 )))
```

[image: SOLUTION]

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I am pulling the ip addresses out of text strings anyway so breaking it up into octets is no problem. I used some basic private addresses as an example but my data has a mixture of public and private IP addresses if that makes any sense. so they could start with. 10.50.., 172.30.. or 203...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by tightest range and widest range for validity.  Consider the ranges as non-contiguous pools of addresses and check if the the address fits into any of them..

Comment: I have amended my answer to work with any IP, and check for addresses fall within MIN(start) and MAX(end) (forget the tightest, i overgthought it).

Comment: That is fantastic. You are a genius. Just fixed up some error correction in the min / max. and put the validation in F5 to drag down.

Comment: Hi Lana, On a larger sample the validation seems to no longer work.I was then looking at the validation formula and i think there is an issue with it. for =IF(AND(B6>$I$1,B6<$O$1).. checks the whole range (or seems to) and decides that if anything falls b/n 0 and say 200 it passes for the first octet. which everything does.  The ranges are not contiguous though so i am getting incorrect results. I may be missing something...

Comment: @Drew, that bit of formula that youve quoted indeed does that, and that's how I understood comparison should be working.  Can you amend your sample to include what you just mentioned? I like a good puzzle, but it's not a good use of time if i have to keep guessing :))